# How to redirect wildcard subdomain to my domain

Tags: web, apache2, subdomain, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain

I would like to redirect wildcard subdomain to my actual domain.

like this (I already have error.example.com)

dsfas.example.com -> error.example.com

but I could not do this after hours of searching. Is there a solution to this.

I am using apache

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a “catch-all” Apache configuration and redirecting to the domain you specify.

Create an Apache configuration file with a name like `zzz-catchall.conf` (so that it’s the last file alphabetically in the directory) and paste this into the file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin none@noaddy.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/catch/public

        ServerName catch.example.com
        ServerAlias *.example.com *.*
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/catch-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/catch-access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/catch/public>
               Options FollowSymLinks
               AllowOverride All

               Order Allow,Deny
               Allow From All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Be sure to change the domain names and directories accordingly.

In the `/var/www/catch/public` (or whatever) directory, you can set up a redirect a number of ways, but `.htaccess` would be simple enough:

```
Redirect 301 / https://error.example.com/
```

Ensure the virtual host configuration file is enabled, and reload Apache. That should get you going